# Kick members with role Discord bot Python

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want to add a function to kick users who have a certain role. But nothing works out.I was looking for solutions, but they all did not help. Sometimes the team worked, but did not identify people with the right role and no one was kicked

```
from discord.ext import commands
import sys
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import re
from discord.ext.commands import *
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason==None:
      reason=" no reason provided"
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(f'Пользователь {member.mention} был кикнут по причине {reason}')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def clearall(ctx):
  await ctx.channel.purge()

bot.run("Token")
```

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kickMembers(ctx, role: discord.Role, reason: str = None):
    await ctx.reply('Kicking members')

    for member in role.members:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)

    await ctx.reply('Members kicked')
```

This code works, but it doesn't see people with the role. King's attempt is being carried out, but people with roles are not kicking

Answer (score 0):

Hey The only small problem is this line

intents = discord.Intents.default()

the bot basically don't have the rights to kick someone with the default intents

how to solve it replace this line

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
```

with

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```